# I need to retrieve total rows affected on top of limiting my search - Node/Express/SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, express

I am creating pagination for one of my calls. I need to retrieve the total rows that would be affected regardless of the page selected. I also need to retrieve just the objects for that page only. It makes sense to create two queries. However, I'm unsure how to go about this because I keep getting back errors.

`route.js`:

```
-- This query is for retrieving the total affected and sending the pagination header, with no response sent
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {

        let sqlString = `
        SELECT dt.[dataID]
        FROM DataTable dt with (nolock)
        `
        return pool.request().query(sqlString)
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result, result.rowsAffected[0], 'logging result')
        let rows = result.recordset

        let paginationHeader = {
            totalCount: result.rowsAffected[0],
            pageSize: req.query.pageSize,
            currentPage: req.query.pageNumber
        }
        res.setHeader('X-Pagination', JSON.stringify(paginationHeader))
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Pagination', JSON.stringify(paginationHeader))
        sql.close();
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err})
        sql.close();
    });
})

-- This query is for retrieving the objects for that page.
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {

        let sqlString = `
        SELECT dt.[dataID]
        FROM DataTable dt with (nolock)
        ORDER BY c.Description OFFSET @pageNumber ROWS FETCH NEXT @size ROWS ONLY 
        `

        return pool.request().input('size', sql.Int, req.query.pageSize).input('pageNumber', sql.Int, req.query.pageNumber).query(sqlString)
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result, result.rowsAffected[0], 'logging result')
        let rows = result.recordset

        res.status(200).json(rows);
        sql.close();
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err})
        sql.close();
    });
})
```

I need to combine the two somehow. Thanks.

Comment: And the errors are...?

Comment: The instance above, the request was stalling, therefore not getting anything back including errors, assuming because it's only reading the first query and since there's nothing being sent, it's just waiting. I consider this an error because it's not what I want.

Comment: Are you referring to top most query as the first query? As far as I can tell, the only reason the `SELECT` query could be blocked is due a transaction occurring. See if removing `with (nolock)` helps?

Comment: My fault for not specifying, yes that is correct. I'm getting the same result. When I log the results, I'm only retrieving the topmost query and not the one underneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that only the first of 2 identical `router.get()`'s will be executed, so that is your primary problem.

You could combine them into the single `.get()` as follows:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
     let sqlString = `
     SELECT dt.[dataID]
     FROM DataTable dt with (nolock)
     `
     return pool.request().query(sqlString);

   }).then(result => {
     console.log(result, result.rowsAffected[0], 'logging result')
     let rows = result.recordset

     let paginationHeader = {
        totalCount: result.rowsAffected[0],
        pageSize: req.query.pageSize,
        currentPage: req.query.pageNumber
     }
     res.setHeader('X-Pagination', JSON.stringify(paginationHeader))
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Pagination', JSON.stringify(paginationHeader))
     sql.close();

     /* BEGIN - added code from your second proc */
     return new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect()
  }).then(pool => {
     let sqlString = `
     SELECT dt.[dataID]
     FROM DataTable dt with (nolock)
     ORDER BY c.Description OFFSET @pageNumber ROWS FETCH NEXT @size ROWS ONLY 
     `

     return pool.request().input('size', sql.Int, req.query.pageSize).input('pageNumber', sql.Int, req.query.pageNumber).query(sqlString)
  }).then(result => {
     console.log(result, result.rowsAffected[0], 'logging result')
     let rows = result.recordset

     sql.close();
     res.status(200).json(rows);
  }).catch(err => {
     console.log(".catch ERROR: ", err);
     sql.close();
     res.status(500).send({ message: err})
  });
});
```

I just concat.ed the code from your second `router.get()` together with that from your first one.

Cheers!

Comment: Add a console.log() msg in the .catch. Perhaps that will give you a better hint. (I updated the answer with this.)

Comment: Ok I reversed the order and am getting this error - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. It's coming back as 200 but without the headers.

Comment: Yes, `res.status` must occur after all `res.setHeader` settings.

Comment: Ah okay, well it seems to be working now! I don't know what I did before I reversed them ha. Thanks for the help!